# Break Detail Line in Half?

Tags: crystal-reports

#### Currently the detail prints like this:

[image]

#### I want to break the line in half like this:

[image]

#### This is what I have; Not what I want

[image]

#### Notes:

1. This is all in a sub-report if that makes any difference
2. I do not yet grok using formulas, variables, etc. to influence what is printed where, when, or how.
3. I'm working in Visual Studio 2012, I don't know the CR version.
4. I created *Detail a* and *Detail b* sections.
5. I created 2 Group Header Sections: *Group Header 1a* and *Group Header 1b*
6. I moved all the headers into these two groups and suppressed the Report Header Section (but not the Report Footer). Moved report fields into corresponding detail group.
7. Now all the detail is printed after both headers are printed. I expected this but don't know how to do what I need.
8. Totals are printed in the *Report Footer*, no issues here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The Mystery is Solved

1. Created a 2nd sub report
2. Moved desired headings, details, and totals to the new sub report *ReportHeadr*, *DetailSection*, and *ReportFooterSection* respectively.
3. Put the new sub report directly below the original in the same (main report) section - it just happens to be a *GroupHeaderSection*
4. Changed SubReport Links ... for the new sub report. Set it identically to the original.

**Notes**

The sub report links setting is key to making this work. Otherwise I was getting all the data records every time this new sub report was generated, resulting in hundreds of pages.

Could not use Siva's answer. The sub report happens to be inside a Main Report's *GroupHeaderSection*. The report's structure does not make putting the (sub report) content into new groups and detail sections possible.

I did create multiple groups & detail sections in the sub report itself. This still gives me the undesired results illustrated in the original question posting.

Answer (score -1):

if you need to view the output as you required follow below 
1. Take 2 detail sections add two sub reports in main report.
2. In sub report 1 place first 3 columns and in second sub report place other two columns

Comment: You cannot nest subreports and OP is already working from within a subreport.

Comment: @Ryan... where did I ask to use nested sub reports..my approach is correct o would advice you to reconsider downvote... downvoting is ment to correct the answer but nor to downvote correct answer

Comment: Read the question. You are asking OP to insert a subreport into a subreport. I can't remove the downvote until you revise the answer.

Comment: Read my answer and spot me where I asked to use a sub report inside sub report...I know thst nested subreport is not possible in crystal reports

Comment: @Ryan I have just changed my answer and made it more verbose.